# erro com função de arlert que eu criei

Tags: php, javascript

Galera montei uma função bem simples de alert em php. Ele funciona porém esta apresentando um problema.

Sempre que eu chamo ele assim:

```
Alert("Pedido finalizado");
```

Ela funciona, porém quando coloco um \n para ter uma quebra se linha, ela não funciona. Exemplo:

```
Alert("Pedido \n finalizado");
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? no navegador o único erra que aparece e este:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF
```

Bom segue a função:

```
function Alert($msn){
?>
<script>
    alert('<?=$msn?>');
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: deu certo assim. mas não entendi o porque

Comment: Quando você usa `\n` na variável, ela já interpreta o scape, e quando passa pro alert, ele não está mais lá. Usando dois, ela interpreta um, e o alert outro.

Comment: OK muito obrigado pela ajuda e exlicação

Comment: Mas, outra coisa, não entendo muito de php, mas esse <script> não deveria vir em um `ècho` algo assim, acho que o erro EOF se refere a isso. Ou não? (tirando dúvida :P )

Comment: Ele funciona em echo tbm, porém assim o código fica muito mais organizado. E a questão do EOF era o \\n

Comment: Ah ok, tá certo. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é o que está acontecendo:

```
<script>
    alert('Pedido
finalizado');
</script>
```

Para resolver isso o `\` teria que ser escapado com um `\`.

```
Alert("Pedido \\n finalizado");
```

E assim:

```
<script>
    alert('Pedido\nfinalizado');
</script>
```